# Spring RestTemplate returns 'text/html' even though I set 'Accept' header to 'application/json'

Tags: json, spring, spring-boot, rest, resttemplate

I receive a *"Could not extract response: no suitable HttpMessageConverter found for response type [interface java.util.Map] and content type [text/html;charset=iso-8859-1]"* message even though I set 'Accept' header to 'application/json' in the below request :

```
        HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
        headers.setAccept(Arrays.asList(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON));
        headers.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);
        HttpEntity entity = new HttpEntity(headers);

        ResponseEntity<Map> responseEntity =  new RestTemplate().exchange(
                "http://api.dbpedia-spotlight.org/en/annotate?text=" +
                        cut +
                        "&confidence=0.5&support=0&spotter=Default&disambiguator=Default&policy=whitelist&types=&sparql="
                , HttpMethod.GET,entity, Map.class);
```

I made this request on Postman, setting 'Accept' header to 'application/json' and received a json response but with Java it returns html.

Comment: Are you really doing the same as in Postman as I actually doubt it. I suspect you get an error page instead of a result.

Comment: Without privoding Accept header, the service returns an xml response with Content-Type: text/html

Comment: it retusn html not xml.

Comment: There is a redirect (`http` → `https`) – try to use `https` directly in your code.